# Is there any good reason to use Server Side Includes as opposed to include in a LAMP environment

Tags: php, apache2, ssi

I was just curious, would there be any good justification for using `SSI` instead of PHP's `include` in a LAMP environment? I cannot really think of any good argument in favor of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Don't use SSIs.  If you are only including 100% static HTML, (not another `include()` or anything) use `readfile()` .. Else, just use `include()` and make sure any random person can't write to those files as I would hope anyone would do.

SSI includes can be a major pain since they're dependent on Apache in particular (try getting nginx to read SSI's .. it's NOT fun) and have zero advantage EXCEPT ......

If the file in question, whether is to be SSI included, or PHP included -- if it has insecure write permissions or for any reason an untrusted source is able to write to it,  it becomes a major concern.  Keep in mind, when you `include()` then you are executing  PHP code.

There are SSI directives that can do exec as well (`#exec`), which is also dangerous, but may have a more limited scope than PHP itself (or, it **might** be even more dangerous, that is extremely dependent and subjective to each particular situation)

However, if the file in question you want to include does not, and never will, contain PHP code and only HTML, please do not use `include()`, instead use:

```
echo file_get_contents('filename.html');
```

As this will be much safer, as nothing is ever executed.  Or you could also use readfile, which may be more effecient if you're handling very large (10MB+) files being included:

```
readfile('filename.html');
```

Therefore, it may be a slight opinion of mine that you should use PHP instead of SSI, but I can tell you from experience SSI's can become unmanagable and have no more benefit than at least `file_get_contents()` or `readfile()`, while `include()` has the special feature that if it contains PHP code (good or bad), it will be executed.

Comment: Nginx does support SSI very well. There are some circumstances where SSI can really be helpfull e.g. when an application caches rendered pages and you need to clear the cache but don't want to clear all pages cause of a menu change. Then you could just replace the menu or several menus by an include and just clear the menu files on a change an leave the cached pages intact.